# How to get the file path for the picked files from the external storage in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file

I am facing the issues in picking the file path of the file, i searched for all over the stack overflow but the issue is not solved .Code  for picking the files from the device is shown below.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
           intent.setType("*/*");
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
           //intent.addFlags(ST)
           startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose File to Upload.."), PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
```

The picked files from intent are get by

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
       if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST) {
           if (data != null) {
               //no data present
               Uri uri = data.getData();
              String filePath = data.getData().getPath();
        //       String path = uri.getPath();
               file = new File(filePath);

               String name = getContentName(getContentResolver(), uri);
               try {
                   InputStream inStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               try {
                   bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);

               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

               LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
               linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                       LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
               linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

               ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
               imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
               attachFile.addView(imageView);


               TextView textView = new TextView(this);
               textView.setText(name);
               attachFile.addView(textView);

               return;
           }

       }
   }
```

}

In the above code file path is obtained by the ` String filePath = data.getData().getPath(); but when uploading the files to the server exception is thrown like invalid document and file .How to get the correct path of the file from the uri ?

But the name of the file is picked by using

```
`public static String getContentName(ContentResolver resolver, Uri uri) {
       Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
       cursor.moveToFirst();
       int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
       if (nameIndex >= 0) {
           return cursor.getString(nameIndex);
       } else {
           return null;
       }
   }`
```

How to get the correct file path for the picked file ?

Answer (score 1):

> How to get the correct file path for the picked file ?

You don't. There is no file. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` has little to do with files. It has everything to do with content.

Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to work with the content identified by the `Uri`. For uploading, either:

- Give the `InputStream` to the uploading API, if it can upload from that, or
- Use the `InputStream` and a `FileOutputStream` to some file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`) to make a copy of the content, then upload from your local copy