# How to convert the uri to inputStream data and upload the stream data into server?

Tags: android, android-ion

I am working the task in picking the file from the gallery and upload the picked file to the server.

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
       if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST) {
           if (data != null) {
               //no data present
               Uri uri = data.getData();
              String filePath = data.getData().getPath();
        //       String path = uri.getPath();
               file = new File(filePath);

               String name = getContentName(getContentResolver(), uri);
               try {
                   InputStream inStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               try {
                   bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);

               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

               LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
               linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                       LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
               linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

               ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
               imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
               attachFile.addView(imageView);


               TextView textView = new TextView(this);
               textView.setText(name);
               attachFile.addView(textView);

               return;
           }

       }
   }
```

I poicked the file by using intent

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
       intent.setType("*/*");
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
       //intent.addFlags(ST)
       startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose File to Upload.."), PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
```

My issue is the uri data is converted the inputStream but i am using the ion library in that inputstream files cannot be uploaded to server.
How to convert the inputStream to outputstream to save in getCacheDir().I refered this site [How to get the file path for the picked files from the external storage in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762230/how-to-get-the-file-path-for-the-picked-files-from-the-external-storage-in-andro)

Please help me how to upload the InputStream data into the ion library.

Comment: use `InputStream inStream` for reading, now you are not using it

Comment: @ pskink I don't know how to use the InputStream ..if you know means please help me

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html, see `read()` methods (of course the two with `byte[] b` are the variants you should use)

Comment: Then how to use the outputstream

Comment: by reading `OutputStream` documentation first?

Comment: I read the outputstream but i dont know how to upload the inputstream data into server

Comment: no, you read the inputstream

Comment: i read the inputStream

Comment: and what methods of `OutputStream` are you using to write your data?

Answer (score 18):

In the below code i have passed the uri into the inputstream and and then crated the file and inputStream data are written in outputstream.
This works 100% try this method.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST) if (data != null) {
                //no data present
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String filePath = data.getData().getPath();

                String name = getContentName(getContentResolver(), uri);
             File   file = new File(getCacheDir(),name);

                int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

                try {
                  InputStream  inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                    Log.e("InputStream Size","Size " + inputStream);
                  int  bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();
//                    int bufferSize = 1024;
                   int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];

                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    int read = 0;
                    while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
                    }
                    Log.e("File Size","Size " + file.length());
                    inputStream.close();
                    outputStream.close();

                    file.getPath();
                    Log.e("File Path","Path " + file.getPath());
                    file.length();
                    Log.e("File Size","Size " + file.length());

                    if(file.length() > 0){
                        attachementImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }


                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
               }
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                attachFile.addView(imageView);

                attachFile.addView(textView);

                return;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: yes its works but copying video files won't play by any player it get corrupted.

Comment: With Large files it will Throw `OutOfMemoryException`